# Workplace switcher frozen can't select workspace

Tags: workspaces

After clicking the Workplace Switcher the screen froze and no desktop could be selected. I could still type commands in a terminal window even though the workspace could not be selected. No key combination worked to select a desktop. Alt-F4, Ctrl-alt left/right, etc.

This is a 2x2 workspace, usually with lots of windows open. Clicking on the icon on the taskbar then selecting the workspace to go to (because alt-tab / ctrl-alt-tab is annoying and unpredictable) usually works well.

Other than Raising the Elephant, a soft boot, or a hard boot, is there another way out of this when the workplace switcher is frozen on Ubuntu 16.04? A key combination or other method perhaps?

There was nothing in journalctl that seemed to be related to this freezing event.

[image: Ubuntu workplace switcher frozen]

Comment: Since you have to ask, you will most likely encounter other issues if you proceed.  Considering that you have shell access, you could always kill X and restart it, but restarting the system would be the best solution.  I suggest you take a look at your system logs for indications of a problem which would concur with the freeze to hopefully correct the cause.

Comment: Did you try killing Compiz? In my experience, it's what causes Ubuntu's default interface to freeze and killing it often resolves the freeze. To do that, log in on a text console (press `Ctrl+Alt+F1`) or over the network, and run `pkill compiz`.

Comment: Yes, Ctrl-Alt-F1 certainly fixes it. I suspect it will fix just about anything, in the same way a screwdriver can fix just about anything. In this scenario it is an acceptable answer. It at least gets you to a prompt. I'd like to kill Compiz..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this happens the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>F8</kbd> may not work. Opening a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and using the following command fixes the problem:

```
unity  &> /dev/null & disown
```

This also works well if it is possible to type in a terminal window.